# Adding annotations for High and Low pressure symbols in Mean Sea Level Pressure field

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, metpy

I'm currently plotting the Mean Sea Level Pressure (MSLP) data from [ERA5 Reanalysis](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15Ev8XVL5JDLnubU-YWWYokXRqmuNzAi9/view?usp=sharing) (sample netcdf data is included) using the 'recipe' from [Unidata](https://unidata.github.io/python-gallery/examples/HILO_Symbol_Plot.html).

The reproducible code *(I tried to be as minimal as I can)* runs like this

````
```python
from datetime import datetime
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import metpy.calc as mpcalc
from metpy.units import units
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter
import xarray as xr

#This function is from Unidata recipe as indicated above used for plotting max/min points 
def plot_maxmin_points(lon, lat, data, extrema, nsize, symbol, color='k',
                       plotValue=True, transform=None):
    
    from scipy.ndimage import maximum_filter, minimum_filter

    if (extrema == 'max'):
        data_ext = maximum_filter(data, nsize, mode='nearest')
    elif (extrema == 'min'):
        data_ext = minimum_filter(data, nsize, mode='nearest')
    else:
        raise ValueError('Value for hilo must be either max or min')

    mxy, mxx = np.where(data_ext == data)

    for i in range(len(mxy)):
        ax.text(lon[mxy[i], mxx[i]], lat[mxy[i], mxx[i]], symbol, color=color, size=24,
                clip_on=True, horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center',
                transform=transform)
        ax.text(lon[mxy[i], mxx[i]], lat[mxy[i], mxx[i]],
                '\n' + str(np.int(data[mxy[i], mxx[i]])),
                color=color, size=12, clip_on=True, fontweight='bold',
                horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='top', transform=transform)

#Open the included ERA5 data in this post
ds = xr.open_dataset('EU_Single Levels.nc')

lats = ds.latitude
lons = ds.longitude

# Select and grab data
mslp = ds['msl']

# Apply gaussian filter to the MSLP
mslp_surf = gaussian_filter(mslp.data[30], sigma=3.0) * units.pascal
mslp_hpa = mslp_surf.to(units.hectopascal)

mapcrs = ccrs.PlateCarree()

datacrs = ccrs.PlateCarree()

# Create plot axes with proper projection
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(14, 12))
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection=datacrs)
ax.set_extent([105, 140, 0, 25], mapcrs)

# Plot MSLP Contour
MSLP_range = np.arange(995, 1010, 2)
prs = ax.contour(lons, lats, mslp_hpa, MSLP_range, colors='k',
                 transform=datacrs)
ax.clabel(prs, fmt='%d')

#Should annotate highs and low pressure areas...not working?
plot_maxmin_points(lons, lats, mslp_hpa, 'max', 50, symbol='H', color='b', transform=datacrs)
plot_maxmin_points(lons, lats, mslp_hpa, 'min', 25, symbol='L', color='r', transform=datacrs)

ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE.with_scale('10m'), linewidth=1.15)

plt.title('ERA5 Reanalysis: MSLP (hPa)', loc='left')

plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0, top=1)
plt.show()
```
````

Which produces a plot like this:

[image]

Unfortunately, I ran into some problems when the MSLP plot never 'displayed' the annotations of the MSLP max/min points from the function as created by Unidata. In fact, it also shows a:

> DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future. mxy, mxx = np.where(data_ext == data)

Is there a way to possibly sort out this small issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It does not plot anything because the line `mxy, mxx = np.where(data_ext == data)` return empty arrays.

You are making an elementwise comparison between arrays whose elements are respectively `float32` (in `data_ext`, returned by `maximum_filter`) and `Quantity` objects created by the `pint` package, dealing with units (in `data`). Eventhough numbers can be the same, the elementwise comparison will fail (indicated by the warning), and therefore return `False` everywhere.

To fix this, you can change `mxy, mxx = np.where(data_ext == data)` to `mxy, mxx = np.where(data_ext == np.array(data))`.

Two sides note:

- Having imports inside a function is a bad habit, as it will run the imoprt each time you run the function. Therefore, move `from scipy.ndimage import maximum_filter, minimum_filter` with the other imports.
- The function you use to catch the extrema actually return the max/min of box centered on a pixel, and whose size is fixed by your parameter `nsize`. Therefore, `nsize` should reflect the 'localness' of what you are looking for, here your pressure structures. As your image size is `(101, 141)`, using a box size of 50 will be too big to capture these structures.

Comment: Hello @Liris. When I instead use `mxy, mxx = np.where(data_ext == np.array(data))`, it now says an; `Index error: Too many indices` particularly highlighting the `lon[mxy[i], mxx[i]]`.

Comment: In you function, `lat` and `lon` should be 2D arrays (as also mentioned in the documentation of the function you copied from Unidata), while `lats` and `lons` are 1D. I can't know for sure what these arrays should be, but I guess they might be those corresponding to `lat, lon = np.meshgrid(lats, lons)`.

Comment: Sorry, it should be `lon, lat = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)`. Equivalently, I think you can also replace in the plotting function `lon[mxy[i], mxx[i]], lat[mxy[i], mxx[i]]` by `lon[mxx[i]], lat[mxy[i]]`